# Adb reverse on FireTV fails with error: more than one device/emulator

Tags: react-native, amazon-fire-tv

Running a React Native application with Leanback on Firestick.

This only happens on Firetv stick 4k. I am pretty sure I have only one device connected

`$ adb devices`

`List of devices attached 10.x.x.x:5555   device`

I have no problems running the same on Chromecast. There are no Firewall restrictions.

The error I get is:
`adb: error: more than one device/emulator`

`warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": Command failed: adb -s 10.x.x.x:5555 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution i'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: I've faced the same issue. didn't find any solution